# Pass multiple dropdowns, each having mutiple values selected to controller in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i have list of dynamic generated workout and excercises.Excercises are commom for all workouts.
I need to pass mutiple excercises for each workout.
I need to pass data like this.For workout1 there may be 3 excercises.For workout2 there may be 2 excercises and so on.

**View is:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddWorkoutSessionExcercises", "Trainer", FormMethod.Post))
 {
   foreach (var workoutType in Model.WorkoutTypes)
    {
    <div><span>@workoutType.WorkoutTypeName</span><span class="MandatoryStar">*</span>         </div>

    <div >
        @Html.DropDownList("ExcerciseDDFor", Model.Excercises, null, new {  multiple = "multiple"})
    </div>
}
```

**My Model is like this.Returning list of workout and excercises.**

```
public class AddSessionExcerciseModel
{

    public AddSessionExcerciseModel()
    {
        Excercises = Utility.GetAllExcercises();
        WorkoutTypes = Utility.GetWorkoutTypes();
    }
    public List<SelectListItem> Excercises { get; set; }
    public List<tblWorkoutType> WorkoutTypes { get; set; }
 }
```

**My controller is :**

```
public ActionResult AddWorkoutSessionExcercises(Guid[] ExcerciseDDFor)
{
// code 
}
```

This is passing an array of all excercises for all workouts and i am unable to differentiate that to which workout this excercise belongs.

Is there any way to solve this problem.Or any way that i'll get Excercises arrays for all workouts.Like:

workout1-->Array[2 excercises]

workout2-->Array[3 excercises]

workout3-->Array[1 excercises]

.
.

Thank You.
.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your model a bit. Right now, you have a list of workouts but only a single list of exercises so there is no way of telling which exercise belongs to which workout.

IMHO, `tblWorkoutType` should each contain a list of Exercises.

And in your Action, you should expect a list of Workouts each having a list of selected Exercises

```
public ActionResult AddWorkoutSessionExcercises(List<tblWorkoutType> workouts)
{
// code 
}
```